# Error on second save of NSManagedObjectContext (deallocated insance)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I've read several threads dealing with similar issues on here, but I just can't figure out what I am over-releasing.  From a detail view controller for a Player object, I push a UITableViewController to select Location objects for that Player:

```
- (void)selectLocations 
{
    LocationSelectionController *vc = [[LocationSelectionController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    vc.player = player;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    [vc release];
}
```

Here is a look at some details of the LocationSelectionController:

```
- (void)saveContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [player managedObjectContext];
    if ([context hasChanges]) {
    NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) { //*** ERROR HERE ***
           // show alert
        }
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // ....

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        // show alert
    }
}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [player managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Location" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFRC = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    aFRC.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFRC;

    [request release];
    [sortDescriptor release];

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
    [_fetchedResultsController release];
    [player release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

The functionality is always perfect the first time I navigate to the LocationSelectionController.  I can interact with the Location objects with no problems at all.  When I pop the view and return to the detail view of the Player object, again there is perfect functionality.  It is only when I push the LocationSelectionController for a second time (even if it is from a different Player object) that there is a crash up attempting to save the context.

```
*** -[LocationSelectionController controllerWillChangeContent:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7026920
```

I've tried using instruments with NSZombie to find the problem, and it points me to an instance of LocationSelectionController.
[image: Instruments Screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handling of the NSFetchedResultsController is screwed up. First, consider this code:

```
NSFetchedResultsController *aFRC = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
aFRC.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = aFRC;
```

If your `fetchedResultsController` property is declared `assign`, this code is more or less correct (although then the semantics are wrong). If the property is declared `retain`, you're leaking a reference to `aFRC` here.

But either way, your deallocation is wrong. In dealloc, you have this:

```
self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
[_fetchedResultsController release];
```

The first line sets the property (and this presumably the `_fetchedResultsController` ivar) to nil, so the second line can never release the object. If the property is declared `retain`, I guess this is an attempt to clean up the leak mentioned above; if it is declared `assign`, this is evidence of the incorrect semantics mentioned above. And even if this worked "correctly", the version in `viewDidUnload` doesn't have that extra release so things are *still* wrong.

Either way, the leaked reference leaves the NSFetchedResultsController alive. Eventually it finds a change, which it tries to send to its delegate. And that, of course, fails because the delegate has long since been deallocated.

---

Chances are good that you never need to assign the fetchedResultsController from outside the implementation of this class. What you really should do then is something like this:

The property `fetchedResultsController` should be declared as:

```
@property (retain, readonly) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
```

Your existing `fetchedResultsController` is fine, except that it should assign the `_fetchedResultsController` ivar directly instead of trying to assign `self.fetchedResultsController`.

Then the dealloc and viewDidUnload methods should each release the object something like this:

```
[_fetchedResultsController release];
_fetchedResultsController = nil;
```

You could also set `_fetchedResultsController.delegate` nil before releasing it, to be extra sure, but the documentation doesn't indicate this is necessary as it does for some other classes.

Comment: You are my hero.  Thanks for a great reply!

Comment: Dear Anomie,  I am having a similar problem with my app.  Can you please check my code here and see if you notice anything? Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815549/getting-an-nsinvalidarguementexception-error

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a different outcome.

In my case, I had some KVO observers in the controller that did not have corresponding removeObserver:forKeyPath: calls in dealloc.