# Getting an NSInvalidArguementException error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I think it may have to do with over-releasing?  It keeps crashing at `if (![managedObjectContext save:&error])` like every third time the method is being called (when I add 3 exercises).

Update: I noticed it happens when I go to and from different routine instances.

```
2011-04-28 04:02:58.160 Curl[8035:707] Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[__NSCFDictionary controllerWillChangeContent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ba1b0 with userInfo (null)
    2011-04-28 04:02:58.353 Curl[8035:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary controllerWillChangeContent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ba1b0'
```

method

```
-(void)addExercise
{   
    if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
    { 
        managedObjectContext = [(CurlAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
        [managedObjectContext retain];
    }

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(exerciseChooser)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    [addButton release];

    NSError *error = nil;

    Exercise *exercise = (Exercise *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    exercise.name = selectedExercise;

    NSLog(@"addExercise theSelectedRoutine:  %@", theSelectedRoutine);

    [theSelectedRoutine addRoutineToExercisesObject:exercise];

    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
    {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
    NSLog(@"addExercise theSelectedRoutine:  %@", theSelectedRoutine);
    [self.routineTableView reloadData];

}
```

Here is full code:

```
@implementation RoutineDayTableViewController

@synthesize fetchedResultsController;
@synthesize exerciseChooserView;
@synthesize routineTableView;
@synthesize managedObjectContext;
@synthesize selectedExercise;
@synthesize entityArray;
@synthesize theSelectedRoutine;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"dealloc");
    [fetchedResultsController release];
    [selectedExercise release];
    [managedObjectContext release];
    [exerciseChooserView release];
    [routineTableView release];
    [entityArray release];
    [theSelectedRoutine release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, imagtaes, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.routineTableView.delegate = self;
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(exerciseChooser)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    [addButton release];

    if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
    { 
        managedObjectContext = [(CurlAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
        [managedObjectContext retain];
    }
    [self loadData];
}

-(void)loadData
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

    NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [entityArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"After managedObjectContext: %@",  managedObjectContext);

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    self.entityArray = mutableFetchResults;

    [request setPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"routineExercises = %@", selectedObject]];    

    [mutableFetchResults release];
    [request release];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    NSLog(@"viewDidUnload");
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.exerciseChooserView = nil;
    self.routineTableView = nil;
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Exercise Editing

-(IBAction)exerciseChooser
{
    RoutineExerciseChooserViewController *routineExerciseChooserViewController = [[[RoutineExerciseChooserViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:routineExerciseChooserViewController animated:YES];
}

-(void)addExercise
{   
    if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
    { 
        managedObjectContext = [(CurlAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
        [managedObjectContext retain];
    }

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(exerciseChooser)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    [addButton release];

    NSError *error = nil;

    Exercise *exercise = (Exercise *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    exercise.name = selectedExercise;

    NSLog(@"addExercise theSelectedRoutine:  %@", theSelectedRoutine);

    [theSelectedRoutine addRoutineToExercisesObject:exercise];

    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
    {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
    NSLog(@"addExercise theSelectedRoutine:  %@", theSelectedRoutine);
    //[self.routineTableView reloadData];
}

-(void)toggleEdit
{
    [self.routineTableView setEditing: !self.routineTableView.editing animated:YES];

    if (self.routineTableView.editing)
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Cancel"];
    else
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [routineTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    Exercise *tempExercise = (Exercise *)[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = tempExercise.name;

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
        // Delete the managed object for the given index path
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
        NSLog(@"fetched results : \n%@\n",[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]);

        // Commit the change.
        NSError *error = nil;

        // Update the array and table view.
        if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
        {
            // Handle the error.
        }
        //[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
    }
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[managedObject valueForKey:@"name"] description];
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    [routineTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

     DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     [detailViewController release];
}

#pragma mark - Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }

    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSLog(@"fetchedResultsController theSelectedRoutine: %@",theSelectedRoutine);
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"ANY exerciseToRoutine == %@", theSelectedRoutine]];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    return fetchedResultsController;

    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];
}    

#pragma mark - Fetched results controller delegate

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.routineTableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.routineTableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.routineTableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.routineTableView;

    switch(type)
    {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.routineTableView endUpdates];
}
@end
```

**Update - This is the new updated code:**

```
@implementation RoutineDayTableViewController

@synthesize fetchedResultsController;
@synthesize exerciseChooserView;
@synthesize routineTableView;
@synthesize managedObjectContext;
@synthesize selectedExercise;
@synthesize theSelectedRoutine;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"dealloc");
    [fetchedResultsController release];
    [selectedExercise release];
    [managedObjectContext release];
    [exerciseChooserView release];
    [routineTableView release];
    [theSelectedRoutine release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, imagtaes, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.routineTableView.delegate = self;
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(exerciseChooser)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    [addButton release];

    if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
    { 
        managedObjectContext = [(CurlAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
        [managedObjectContext retain];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    NSLog(@"viewDidUnload");
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.exerciseChooserView = nil;
    self.routineTableView = nil;
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Exercise Editing

-(IBAction)exerciseChooser
{
    RoutineExerciseChooserViewController *routineExerciseChooserViewController = [[[RoutineExerciseChooserViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:routineExerciseChooserViewController animated:YES];
}

-(void)addExercise
{   
    if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
    { 
        managedObjectContext = [(CurlAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
        [managedObjectContext retain];
    }

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(exerciseChooser)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    [addButton release];

    NSError *error = nil;

    Exercise *exercise = (Exercise *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    exercise.name = self.selectedExercise;

    NSLog(@"addExercise theSelectedRoutine:  %@", theSelectedRoutine);

    [theSelectedRoutine addRoutineToExercisesObject:exercise];

    if (![fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
    {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
    NSLog(@"addExercise theSelectedRoutine:  %@", theSelectedRoutine);
    //[self.routineTableView reloadData];
    [exercise release];
    [error release];
}

-(void)toggleEdit
{
    [self.routineTableView setEditing: !self.routineTableView.editing animated:YES];

    if (self.routineTableView.editing)
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Cancel"];
    else
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [routineTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    Exercise *tempExercise = (Exercise *)[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = tempExercise.name;

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
        // Delete the managed object for the given index path
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
        NSLog(@"fetched results : \n%@\n",[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]);

        // Commit the change.
        NSError *error = nil;

        // Update the array and table view.
        if (![fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
        {
            // Handle the error.
        }
        //[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
    }
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[managedObject valueForKey:@"name"] description];
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    [routineTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

     DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     [detailViewController release];
}

#pragma mark - Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }

    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSLog(@"fetchedResultsController theSelectedRoutine: %@",theSelectedRoutine);
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"ANY exerciseToRoutine == %@", theSelectedRoutine]];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];
    return fetchedResultsController;
}    

#pragma mark - Fetched results controller delegate

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.routineTableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.routineTableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.routineTableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.routineTableView;

    switch(type)
    {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.routineTableView endUpdates];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing two entirely separate means of accessing the Core Data information. You should have only one context reference and one fetch for each tableview. You have at least two fetches operating at the same time and two context references. You need to pick one or the other. If you are using a fetched results controller, then you don't need the code in either `viewDidLoad` and `loadData`.

You also need to use the `self` reference when referring to properties e.g. you need to use `self.selectedExercise` instead of just `selectedExercise`. Only the `self` reference form gives you automatic retention and release.

Comment: Thanks TechZen, I have removed method for `loadData` and variable `entityArray`.  I added self to this line to result in `exercise.name = self.selectedExercise;`.  Is there anything else that I missed?

Comment: At a glance, it looks a lot better. I would recommend using a cast when you get managed objects returned from a fetch e.g. ` Exercise *tempExercise = (Exercise *)[fetche...` You can't always be sure exactly what class you will get back (especially in more complex data models) and casting forces the runtime to try to treat it as the cast class. This can lead to subtle errors down the line.

Comment: Thanks TechZen.  I know what casting is but what do I add after `(Exercise*)`, would it be something like `Exercise *tempExercise = (Exercise *)[FetchedResultsController alloc]init];` ?

Comment: Also, I am still getting some funny crashes.  If this class seems to be ok now, then the problem may be in its parent tableview, Routine.  Ive posted that class here if you would be so kind as to see if anything sticks out to you as strange. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824139/anything-noticably-wrong-with-my-code

Comment: To remove the cast, just remove the `(Exercise *)` from the line.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues with your code.

- The one most probably causing the error is that the `fetchedResultsController` method leaks a reference to the NSFetchedResultsController, along with a few other objects. The releases must occur before the return, not after.
- Why does `loadData` add a predicate to the request after using it?
- What is even the point of `loadData`? It sets up `entityArray`, which doesn't seem to be used anywhere else. Left over from before you added `fetchedResultsController`?
- `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` deletes an object from `fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext`, but then saves `self.managedObjectContext` instead. This should work since those should always be the same, but it would be more semantically correct to use the same object for both operations.

Comment: Thanks Anomie, so I have deleted `loadData` method and removed `entityArray`. Was the leak you referenced in this method or in the remaining - `(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController method`? I switched the `commitEditingStyle` code to `if (![fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext save:&error])`.   I still, however, am getting the app to crash after adding a few exercise and switching between the routines.

Comment: It crahses the third time I switch between Routines.  Log shows `[CALayer controllerWillChangeContent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5d4bd00` and `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CALayer controllerWillChangeContent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5d4bd00'`.